# Two hadoop nodes on same machine while a second machine not joining the cluster

Tags: hadoop, configuration, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

I have a test cluster of two machines, on both of them hadoop is installed. I've configured the hadoop cluster but on admin UI (as in the below picture) I see that two nodes are running on the same master machine, and that the other machine has no Hadoop node.

[image]

On master machine following services are running:

```
~$ jps
26310 ResourceManager
27593 Jps
26216 DataNode
26135 NameNode
26557 NodeManager
26701 JobHistoryServer
```

On the slave machine:

```
~$ jps
2614 DataNode
2920 Jps
2707 NodeManager
```

I don't why the slave is not joining the cluster (It was before). I tried to shutdown all servers on both machines and format HDFS then restarting everything but that didn't help. Any help to figure what's causing that behavior is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, the two machines had same hostname! So I just renamed the slave.